# Task switching on iOS 4.3.1?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

I just upgraded my iPod (4gen) from iOS 4.3 to 4.3.1.  Pressing the button twice now no longer brings up the app switcher.

Is there some setting I need to change to bring this back?  I didn't see anything in the [release notes](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1358) about removing or disabling this feature.

Comment: Works on my 3rd gen, for what it's worth.  It's always been a bit finicky timing-wise for me, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with it for a few minutes, and eventually it went back to the old mode where task switching works.  I have no idea why, and I didn't change any setting.

It's not just the speed: I've never had trouble getting task switching to work, and for the first 10 minutes after upgrading, it didn't work no matter how fast I clicked it.  It would zip over to the useless search screen and back really fast.